# OrderingComponentRendererBase overrides final method encodeBegin.(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;Ljavax/faces/component/UIComponent;)

Tags: java, wildfly

I'm using `wildfly 10.1.0`, `jdk 1.8`, `dynamic web module 3.1` and `java serverfaces 2.2`.

When I run this project, I get the following stack trace. I have already checked that no method is overriding the final method of classes as shown in the stack trace.

I'm not certain what is causing this and was hoping someone could help me out.

```
16:30:44,786 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment RGExtranet.war (runtime-name: RGExtranet.war) in 73ms
16:30:44,787 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "RGExtranet.war" (runtime-name: "RGExtranet.war")
16:31:01,805 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry logkit-1.2.jar in /D:/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments/RGExtranet.war/WEB-INF/lib/jacorb.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:31:01,806 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry avalon-framework-4.1.5.jar in /D:/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments/RGExtranet.war/WEB-INF/lib/jacorb.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:31:01,806 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry concurrent-1.3.2.jar in /D:/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments/RGExtranet.war/WEB-INF/lib/jacorb.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:31:01,806 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry antlr-2.7.2.jar in /D:/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments/RGExtranet.war/WEB-INF/lib/jacorb.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:31:01,824 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry activation.jar in /D:/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments/RGExtranet.war/WEB-INF/lib/mail.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:31:02,310 ERROR [org.jboss.as.jsf] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJSF0002: Could not load JSF managed bean class: com.revguru.crs.web.general.vo.AmenityContainer
16:31:02,785 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment RGExtranet.war
16:31:02,967 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-6) Failed to define class org.richfaces.renderkit.OrderingComponentRendererBase in Module "deployment.RGExtranet.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.VerifyError: Failed to link org/richfaces/renderkit/OrderingComponentRendererBase (Module "deployment.RGExtranet.war:main" from Service Module Loader): class org.richfaces.renderkit.OrderingComponentRendererBase overrides final method encodeBegin.(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;Ljavax/faces/component/UIComponent;)V
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:446)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:274)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:78)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:606)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:437)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:274)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:78)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:606)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.loadClassInfoSet(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:259)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.deploy(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:169)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

16:31:02,967 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-6) Failed to define class org.richfaces.renderkit.ListShuttleRendererBase in Module "deployment.RGExtranet.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.VerifyError: Failed to link org/richfaces/renderkit/ListShuttleRendererBase (Module "deployment.RGExtranet.war:main" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link org/richfaces/renderkit/OrderingComponentRendererBase (Module "deployment.RGExtranet.war:main" from Service Module Loader): class org.richfaces.renderkit.OrderingComponentRendererBase overrides final method encodeBegin.(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;Ljavax/faces/component/UIComponent;)V
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:446)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:274)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:78)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:606)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.loadClassInfoSet(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:259)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.deploy(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:169)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

16:31:02,968 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "RGExtranet.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:154)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Failed to link org/richfaces/renderkit/ListShuttleRendererBase (Module "deployment.RGExtranet.war:main" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link org/richfaces/renderkit/OrderingComponentRendererBase (Module "deployment.RGExtranet.war:main" from Service Module Loader): class org.richfaces.renderkit.OrderingComponentRendererBase overrides final method encodeBegin.(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;Ljavax/faces/component/UIComponent;)V
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:446)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:274)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:78)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:606)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.loadClassInfoSet(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:259)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.deploy(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:169)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
    ... 5 more

16:31:02,977 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"RGExtranet.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"RGExtranet.war\".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"RGExtranet.war\"
    Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Failed to link org/richfaces/renderkit/ListShuttleRendererBase (Module \"deployment.RGExtranet.war:main\" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link org/richfaces/renderkit/OrderingComponentRendererBase (Module \"deployment.RGExtranet.war:main\" from Service Module Loader): class org.richfaces.renderkit.OrderingComponentRendererBase overrides final method encodeBegin.(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;Ljavax/faces/component/UIComponent;)V"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"RGExtranet.war\".beanmanager",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"RGExtranet.war\".INSTALL"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"RGExtranet.war\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"RGExtranet.war\".beanmanager]",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"RGExtranet.war\".batch.environment is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"RGExtranet.war\".beanmanager]"
    ]
}
16:31:02,997 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYSRV0016: Replaced deployment "RGExtranet.war" with deployment "RGExtranet.war"
16:31:02,997 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".INSTALL
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "RGExtranet.war"
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGWeb.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."RGWeb.war".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "RGWeb.war"
```

List of libraries I am using:

```
antlr-2.7.7.jar
aopalliance.jar
artemis-commons-1.1.0.wildfly-011.jar
asm-3.3.1.jar"/>
asm-attrs.jar
avalon-framework-4.1.4.jar
axis-1.4.jar
batik-awt-util-1.6-1.jar
batik-ext-1.6-1.jar
batik-gui-util-1.6-1.jar
batik-util-1.6-1.jar
c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar
cdi-api-1.1.jar
cglib-2.2.jar
classmate-1.3.0.jar
commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
commons-cli-1.2.jar
commons-codec-1.3.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar
commons-digester-1.6.jar
commons-discovery-0.2.jar
commons-el-1.0.jar" 
commons-email-1.0.jar
commons-fileupload-1.0.jar
commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
commons-io-1.3.2.jar
commons-lang-2.3.jar
commons-logging.jar
commons-net-2.0.jar
commons-pool-1.3.jar
commons-validator-1.3.1.jar
cssparser-0.9.18.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
ehcache-2.10.3.jar
el-api-2.2.jar
geolatte-geom-1.0.6.jar
geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
groovy-all-2.4.7.jar
guava-18.0.jar
hibernate-annotations.jar"
hibernate-c3p0-5.2.6.Final.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar
hibernate-ehcache-5.2.6.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.7.Final.jar
hibernate-infinispan-5.2.6.Final-tests.jar
hibernate-infinispan-5.2.6.Final.jar"/>
hibernate-jbosscache2.jar 
hibernate-jmx-3.5.2-final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
hibernate-osgi-5.2.6.Final.jar
hibernate-proxool-5.2.6.Final.jar
hibernate-spatial-5.2.6.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-5.2.3.Final.jar
hornetq-commons-2.4.7.Final.jar
infinispan-commons-8.1.0.Final.jar
infinispan-core-8.2.5.Final.jar
istack-commons-runtime-2.21.jar
istack-commons-tools-2.21.jar
iText-2.1.7.jar
iText-rtf-2.1.7.jar
jacorb.jar
jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar
jasperreports-3.6.0.jar
jasypt-1.5.jar
javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar
javax.faces-api-2.2.jar
javax.inject-1.jar
javax.persistence-2.1.0-rc1.jar
jaxrpc.jar
jboss-common-logging-log4j-2.0.4.GA.jar
jboss-faces.jar
jboss-interceptors-api_1.1
jboss-javaee.jar
jboss-jmx-4.3.0.GA_CP03.jar
jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar
jboss-marshalling-osgi-1.4.10.Final.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar"/>
jbosscache-core.jar
jbosscache-pojo.jar
jcip-annotations.jar
jfreechart-1.0.12.jar
jfreechart-1.0.12.jar
jgroups-3.6.7.Final.jar
jna-4.1.0.jar
jna-platform-4.1.0.jar
jsf-api-2.2.9.jar
jsf-facelets-1.1.15.B1.jar
jsf-impl-2.1.21.jar
jsr250-api-1.0.jar
jta.jar
jts-1.13.jar
jxl-2.6.jar
log4j1.2.17.jar
mail.jar
mchange-commons-java-0.2.11.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.10-bin.jar
org.osgi.compendium-4.3.1.jar
org.osgi.core-4.3.1.jar
oro-2.0.8.jar
persistence.jar
picketbox-commons-1.0.0.final.jar
poi-3.9.jar
poi-contrib-3.6.jar
poi-ooxml-3.9.ja
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9.jar
poi-scratchpad-3.9.jar
postgresql-9.4-1200-jdbc41.jar
proxool-0.8.3.jar
quartz-2.2.1.jar
richfaces-a4j-4.5.17.Final.jar
richfaces-api-3.3.3.Final.jar
richfaces-core-4.5.17.Final.jar
richfaces-impl-3.3.4.Final.jar
richfaces-page-fragments-4.5.17.Final.jar
richfaces-rich-4.5.17.Final.jar
richfaces-ui-3.3.4.Final.jar
saaj.jar
sac-1.3.jar
servlet-api.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar
slf4j-simple-1.7.7.jar
spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-aspects-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-instrument-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-instrument-tomcat-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-jms-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-messaging-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar"
spring-orm-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-oxm-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-test-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-portlet-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-websocket-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar
tomahawk-1.1.14-tlddoc.jar
tomahawk-1.1.14.jar
waffle-jna-1.7.jar
xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
xmlParserAPIs-2.0.2.jar
javax.el-3.0.0.jar
javax.servlet-api-3.1.0..jar
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case this error occurs because of conflict of two jars having new and old version

keep jar according to jvm of runtime environment.